# Convert one child element of an XML structure into a Java object

Tags: java, xml, jaxb, jackson, xmpp

I have an XML structure of a message received from an XMPP subscription (below). I only care about the "user" part of this message and would like to convert this into an equivalent "User" object in Java so that I can use it to perform other processing.  Is there a way to achieve this in Java?

The only way I know I can do it is to use Jackson annotations (e.g @JsonProperty) and create the equivalent objects for all the parent elements - event, notification, update, data etc - but I don't really care about them so seems like a waste.

Not sure how I can just convert the "user" part to an object and forget about the rest?

```
 <event xmlns='http://jabber.org/protocol/pubsub#event'>
    <notification xmlns='http://jabber.org/protocol/pubsub'>
    <Update>
      <data>
       <user>
        <dialogs>/finesse/api/User/1234/Dialogs</dialogs>
        <extension></extension>
        <firstName>1234</firstName>
        <lastName>1234</lastName>
        <loginId>1234</loginId>
        <loginName>1234</loginName>
        <roles>
         <role>Agent</role>
        </roles>
        <state>LOGOUT</state>
        <stateChangeTime>2015-03-11T14:25:42Z</stateChangeTime>
        <teamId>1</teamId>
        <teamName>Default</teamName>
        <uri>/finesse/api/User/1234</uri>
       </user>
     </data>
    </Update>
   </notification>
  </event>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's a little bit ugly and not optimal for huge xml data, but you could extract user part from xml using for example dom4j and than use Jackson to parse "only user xml" part.

```
    Document doc = new SAXReader().read(...);
    Node user = doc.getRootElement()
            .element("notification")
            .element("Update")
            .element("data")
            .element("user");
    String onlyUserXml = user.asXML();
```